# Admob ad won't disappear when editing text in Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, visibility, admob

Admob is blocking `EditText` when user wants to enter a value. I introduced this code but it is still not working.

```
iAge = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edAge);
iIncome= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edIncome);

iAge.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void   onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
     }
});

iIncome.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How about you try [detecting when the keyboard is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)?

Comment: I don't have the code for that.